# I can not install nslookup in my CentOS server

Tags: centos, yum, nslookup

I can not install `nslookup` in my CentOS 7.2:

```
yum install nslookup
```

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# yum install -y nslookup
added plugin：fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.sunnyvision.com
 * epel: my.mirrors.thegigabit.com
 * extras: mirror.sunnyvision.com
 * updates: mirrors.icidc.com
No available nslookup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nslookup` is contained in `bind-utils` package.

You should use below command to install it:

```
# yum install bind-utils
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yum whatprovides nslookup` to see which package delivers it:

```
~$ yum whatprovides nslookup
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
.
.
32:bind-utils-9.11.4-9.P2.el7.x86_64 : Utilities for querying DNS name servers
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/nslookup



32:bind-utils-9.9.4-74.el7_6.2.x86_64 : Utilities for querying DNS name servers
Repo        : @updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/nslookup
```

Then you can use yum to install the package using `yum install bind-utils`